# document.getElementsByTagName("img"); vs. document.getElementById('testimg');

Tags: javascript

Here is my html

```
<a href="index.php"><img id="testimg"   src="images/logo.png"/></a>
```

Here is my javascript

```
function getW(){
    var theImg = document.getElementById('testimg');
    return theImg;
}

theImg = getW();

if (theImg.width > 119){
    document.write(theImg.width);
}
```

Now when I use this script it out puts the img width

However when I use this script

```
function getW(){
    var theImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); 
    return theImg;
}

theImg = getW();

if (theImg.width > 119){
    document.write(theImg.width);
}
```

It doesn't output anything. What is the difference and why would this 2nd script work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `getElementsByTagName()` returns a set of multiple elements (note the *elements*). You'd need to use `[0]` to get the first matched.

On the other hand, an `id` should always be unique so `getElementById()` returns a reference to a single element.

Comment: What if I want to return all of the img's width on the page?

Comment: @Chris Then you would use a loop on the set returned by `getElementsByTagName()`.

Answer (score 1):

gEBTN returns a node list. Do `theImg[0]` for the first element.

For your other question, do a `for` loop on the `length` of the nodeList.

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName() returns an array of nodes (elements) that match the tag name you provided. So while your first code example returns a single element, your second one is working with an array.

In order to get the image you are looking for through getElementsByTagName, you will need to either need to do an attribute search (finding an appropriate name or id tag, for example) or simply know the order of it on the page.

In your example, theImg[0] will return the image you are looking for.

Comment: I think technically it returns an object, not an array.

Comment: It returns a NodeList object.

Comment: See I know all of these things, but when putting it into words I usually mess it up somehow. I suppose SO will help me clarify my explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Replace on your code:

```
var theImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

with this code:

```
var theImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img").item(0);
```

or with this code:

```
var theImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
```

Both are equivalent, pay attention to the `.item(0)`, it is equivalent to `[0]`.

The zero is correct if the desired image is the first, else replace the zero to a correct index.

Answer (score 0):

The method `document.getElementById('testimg')` returns a real element object whose id is `testimg`. the method `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` will return an array including all element objects whose tag is `img`.

But if there are more than one element whose id is `testimg`, the method `document.getElementById('testimg')` will return the first one.